# Hog-Hof motion feature extraction from videos

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I searched a lot about motion feature extraction from videos , and I realized that describing videos using Histogram of oriented gradient and histogram of oriented optical flow reaches the state of the art!

But I can't deeply understand how that works?! .. I'm thinking that I might use HOG descriptors for each frame and track the results using optical flow , then append the two histogram descriptors together in the same feature vector.

Is that way seems right?! .. or is there another common known way to merge HOG and HOF descriptors in one accurate feature vector?!